# Using MysqlDb in python converts null to None

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-python

Below is my code

```
import MysqlDB as mob

Mysqlconn = mdb.connect(hostname, username, password, databasename,port=3306,cursorclass=mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
Mysqlcur = self.Mysqlcon.cursor()
Mysqlcur.execute("Select * from users where date = %(date_check)s,{"date_check":current_date})
row = self.Mysqlcur.fetchall()
fileOpen = open("filename.csv","w")
for each in row:
    fileOpen.write(str(each["A"])+","+str(each["B"]))
```

It works fine for the rows which does not have null values.
When it encounters a null value for a column, it automatically inserts "None" instead of null.

How do I avoid inserting None?

Datatype for null columns could be timestamp or string.

Has anybody faced such issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Connectors in Python will always automatically convert from the native values in the DB to the appropriate Python type. This won't happen only with MySQL.

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that you want an "SQLish" text output out of your program. In normal code, None is a much more suitable value and the correct representation of an SQL "Null"  in Python terms.

However, the str representation of None is "None" - if you want Null, the easiest work around in the code above is to write an expression on the place you cerce your values to `str`, so that if the value is 'None', it gets the string 'null' instead.

That can be done with ternary `if` inside each call to `str`:

```
fileOpen.write(str(each["A"] if each["A"] is not None else "null")+","+str(each["B"] if each["B"] is not None else "null"))
```

Of course, you should want to use string formating, isnetad of concatenating strings with "+" :

```
fileOpen.write("{},{}".format(
    each["A"] if each["A"] is not None else "null",
    each["B"] if each["B"] is not None else "null",
)
```

Or, if your values are never the empty string or numeric 0, you can use the `or` operator shortcut instead of the ternary `if`

```
fileOpen.write("{},{}".format(
    each["A"] or "null", 
    each["B"] or "null"
)
```

Comment: After writing this into a cvs file, I actually push this data in another database. So, if a timestamp column contains null in mysql, it gets converted to None in python. When I try to push this data in Redshift, it fails, as the column in redshift expects timestamp and None is not timestamp.

Comment: And so, what is the problem witht he code above? Each of the 3 snippets show how can you replace the None with another value on your output - if youd don  want the 'null' string, just put somethign else in there.

Comment: Thank you @jsbueno . It worked. I replace "null" with " " . I also learnt a new format for writing files. I always thought we need to convert each columns to string and then concat it.

Comment: Actually, since you are generating CSV files, you should better use Python's CSV module - as it can automatically handle comples quoting for you. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html