# Don't convert NULL value to empty string when exporting mysql data to csv

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pymysql

I am using pymysql cursor to export data from mysql to csv, something like this:

```py
cur = conn.cursor()
c = csv.writer(open(csvFilePath, "w",newline='',encoding='utf-8'))
for row in cur:
  c.writerow(list(row))
```

But whenever I encounter a null value in mysql column, cursor is writing an empty string "" in the csv. I want to write "NULL" string in the csv so that I can convert it into null when uploading it to another db like redshift.

Comment: The empty string is the only thing that actually makes sense. There's no value in that field to begin with. The string ``"NULL"` on the other hand is an actual value, containing 4 letters. One, I might add, that can occur as a surname, leading to some really funny situations over the years.

Comment: Why you shouldn't emit `"NULL"` when in reality there's no data: [These unlucky people have names that break computers](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems)

Comment: I wanted to distinguish between empty strings that are actually in data and NULL values (data missing). It would be great if there is a way to write data from mysql to csv and upload csv to redshift while keeping empty string as empty string and null values as null in redshift. Thanks for your suggestion anyways.

Comment: You can use `map` to convert `None` to a replacement value with a ternary operator, eg `list(map(lambda x: x if x is not None else "NULL",row))`, as shown [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504098/using-mysqldb-in-python-converts-null-to-none)

Comment: `pymysql` is not outputting `None` but an empty string. The link you posted uses `MysqlDb` instead of `pymysql`.

Comment: `list` and `map` have nothing to do with pymysql or mysqldb. They are just list functions. Changing the lamda to compare with `""` is trivial.

Comment: What you say means you have a serious problem though - you don't have NULLs. If `pymysql` returns an empty string, it means the field had an empty string. Or the query already replaced NULLs with empty strings. You have no way of knowing which values are null now.

Answer (score 0):

you could manage the proper output from select   instead  of repalce the null value during writing the csv

so try using a proper select for null value

```
  select col1, col2, ifnull(your_possible_null_col, 'NULL'), ...
  from your_table 
  where  ...
```

and you could take a look also at INTO OUTFILE for avoid row by row managing

Comment: [These unlucky people have names that break computers](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems). Like Jennifer Null

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   you comment have not sense to me .. try explain better .. the OP could prefer  N/A ..  or others string and the problem remain the same  ..  each db have a function for manage the mapping of null values ..

Comment: I was hoping if we can achieve it using python instead of editing sql query. May be possible using `raw` pymysql cursor and map them to python objects manually? I couldn't find any resources for `raw` pymysql cursor and its mappings other than this: [mysql-docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorraw.html)

Comment: Why  manage the resulting rows  one by one when you can get the result directly from the query..   ..you should also take a look at  select INTO OUTFILE

Comment: My table has many columns with many nullable among them (and not sure which are nullable). This makes the query too "manual" and is hard to extend my approach to another table. select INTO OUTFILE is good until the table is too large for the outfile command to run out of memory.

Comment: Using parquet format better solves my problem but I don't want to change my whole code to load into dataframe and dump into parquet.

Comment: what do you mean for "parquet format" ?? parquet ?? ..anyway  if   you want change null with a string  .. you have only two choice  ..  or change in sql on repalce each value in string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203588/discussion-between-nihhaar-and-scaisedge).

Comment: Hi @Nihhaar. Did you find a way to get None in csv for NULL value in DB and “” in csv for empty string in DB? I am trying to do same and found this thread but there is no final answer. 
I am open to use anything using Python as far as it doesn’t need row level processing.

Comment: It's been sometime but as far as I remember, MySQLdb will give None in python object for NULL value in DB. You can then decide how the None value gets written in csv.